# Keep getting "FOREIGN KEY constraint failed" in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I am new to django and i am making a multivendor ecommerce website for my final year project. for the past three hours i keep having the foreingnkey constraints error when i want to add products.

please i need someone to help me and solve the problem. i added the traceback and forms.py .

views.py

```
def AddProduct(request):
    """this page will be used for adding products"""
    
    if request.method =='POST':
        form=ProductForm(request.POST)
    
        if form.is_valid():
            model=User 
            
            user=form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/becomeaseller/DashBoard')
    else:
        form=ProductForm()
    
    context={'form':form}
    
    return render(request, 'app/addproduct.html',context)
    
    
    return HttpResponse("enter the details and description of your products")
```

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_seller = models.BooleanField(default=False)







        



class Product_Details(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    product_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category=models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    product_image=models.ImageField(null=True)
    product_description=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    product_price=models.IntegerField()
    product_quantity=models.IntegerField(default=1)
    shop_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    shop_location=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    shop_description=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

forms.py

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Product_Details 
        fields=['product_name','product_price','product_description','category']
```

traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /becomeaseller/DashBoard/AddProduct
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\users\mustapha\desktop\ecommerce\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\users\mustapha\desktop\ecommerce\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\users\mustapha\desktop\ecommerce\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\users\mustapha\desktop\ecommerce\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\users\mustapha\desktop\ecommerce\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\users\mustapha\desktop\ecommerce\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\users\mustapha\desktop\ecommerce\multivendor\app\views.py", line 100, in AddProduct
    user=form.save()
  File "C:\users\mustapha\desktop\ecommerce\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 460, in save
    self.instance.save()
  File "C:\users\mustapha\desktop\ecommerce\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 754, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\users\mustapha\desktop\ecommerce\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 792, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "C:\users\mustapha\desktop\ecommerce\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 895, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\users\mustapha\desktop\ecommerce\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 935, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw,
  File "C:\users\mustapha\desktop\ecommerce\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\users\mustapha\desktop\ecommerce\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1254, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\users\mustapha\desktop\ecommerce\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1397, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\users\mustapha\desktop\ecommerce\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\users\mustapha\desktop\ecommerce\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\users\mustapha\desktop\ecommerce\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrapper
s
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\users\mustapha\desktop\ecommerce\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\users\mustapha\desktop\ecommerce\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\users\mustapha\desktop\ecommerce\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\users\mustapha\desktop\ecommerce\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

Comment: Share the `ProductForm` and the *complete* traceback.

Comment: It also looks quite odd to make `user` the `primary_key` for `Product_Details` that means that for each `User` there is *at most* one `Product_Details` recod? Moreover, it is not very "*Django-ish*" to specify a custom primary key.

Comment: @willem-van-onsem i add the productform.

Answer (score 0):

There are some changes u can make for instance, user should be a foreign key in Products model instead of being primary key since I believe a user can add multiple products
So the the model us:

```
class Product_Details(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

The for the AddProduct method

```
def AddProduct(request):
    """this page will be used for adding products"""
    
    if request.method =='POST':
        form=ProductForm(request.POST)    
        if form.is_valid():
            user=request.user            
            form.save(user=user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/becomeaseller/DashBoard')
    else:
        form=ProductForm()    
    context={'form':form}    
    return render(request, 'app/addproduct.html',context)
```